# What could be the reason behind this kernel panic

Tags: linux, external-hard-drive, kernel, centos-6

My laptop boots from the Fedora,Ubuntu live cd normally.But with Centos live cd there seems 
to be a problem as it displays the below lines.

slab error in kmem_cache_destroy():cache 'Acpi-Operate':can't free all objects
 slab error in kmem_cache_destroy():cache 'Acpi-parse':can't free all objects.
 -
 -
 -
Kernel Panic Not Syncing Attempted to kill init!
-Pid 1 ,comm: init Not tainted 2.6.32-279.e16.i686 #1
 []? panic+0x68/0c11c
 []? do_exit+0x741/0x750
 []? do_group_exit+0x3c/0xa0
 []? sys_exit_group+0x11/0x28
 []? sys_enter_do_call+ox12/0x28
panic occured,switching back to text console.

Is this an issue with my harddisk?There seems to be no problems with the RAM.Would using an external harddisk solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like a serious kernel problem (or perhaps it got tangled up with a bad ACPI table courtesy of BIOS). Or it might be that your LiveCD doesn't read correctly. I'm not familiar with CentOS LiveCD, but check if there is a "check media" option. See if there is a newer version, see if you can boot with `acpi=off` (for a complete list of parameters with some explanation, check <http://linuxpoison.blogspot.com/2010/06/acpi-related-linux-kernel-parameters.html>)

Comment: @vonbrand There seems to be no problem with the liveCD as it worked fine on my desktop.I also tried versions Centos 6.2 and 6.3.

Comment: So it was a bad LiveCD?

Comment: If you tried it on another machine, I've seen CDs reading A-OK n one reader, and completely unreadable by others. So that in itself doesn't rule out a not correctly read LiveCD.

Comment: @vonbrand the other option of disabling the ACPI sounds risky and like last resort option that could cause fans to turn off and cause overheating.Can i instead get away with all this using an external HDD?

Comment: I don't think this is a disk issue per se. See the link, there are other options respect to ACPI. And AFAIU, if ACPI is disabled, the fans will just run full throttle, the machine isn't at risk.